# Recommendation box on page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, recommendation-engine

I would like to have the Facebook Recommendation box on my page fb.com/elizawashere.nl , but even after putting in the address of the company it still isn't showing. Did i mis a checkbox or is it not rolled out on all the pages?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you include the SDK on your page? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You may get more information from here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/